# "An unknown error occurred" while downloading documents

Tags: macos, mac, firefox

I have a 3 year old MacBook Pro and lately I've been getting an error message when I try to download something to my machine using Firefox. This is what it says:

> Download error
>
> /Users/scarletriley/Downloads/*the name of document goes here- no spaces of course!* could not be opened, because an unknown error occurred.
>
> Try saving to a disk first and then opening the file.

What does this mean, and what should I do to fix it?

It downloads fine when using Safari.

Comment: How many space left do you have on your drive?

Comment: (Spaces are not a problem on a Mac.)

Comment: What browsers did you try?

Comment: I have about 25 g on my hard drive, and I have tried it in Firefox.

I just tried it in Safari, and it brought up the pdf, which I was then able to Save As to my desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Searching on google, i found [this page](http://support.mozilla.com/fr/kb/unable+to+download+or+save+files) on the Firefox support pages:

> **Choose a valid download folder in Safari Preferences**
>
> If you receive the error *[filename] could not be saved, because an unknown error occurred*, your problem might be caused by an interaction with the Safari
>   browser and your operating system.
>
> To fix the problem, open Safari's Preferences and change the **Save
>   downloaded files to:** setting to a valid folder (such as your Desktop). 
>   Then restart Firefox.

It may help you fix your problem with Firefox.

Comment: @arko: instead of just including a link to the possible solution, please include some info -- a summary of the link, basic steps to fix, etc.  that makes for a much more useful answer than "i found this page", especially for pages that might be moved or relocated in the future.

Comment: Good point, wondering why i didn't do it... Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

**FIRST** Install a new version of Acrobat.

Then....

1. Go To **Firefox**, **Preferences**
2. Click the **Applications** tab
3. Scroll down to **PDF File**
4. Under **Action** click on the drop down menu next to it.
5. Click **Use other...**
6. Select the **NEW VERSION** of Acrobat that you just installed.